# Como fazer multiplas validações Where com Linq e Mongo no c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mongodb, linq

Estou desenvolvendo uma Api e no meu método GET poderá ser passado palavra a ser pesquisada, data inicial e  data final. Porém todos os campos são opcionais, ou seja, posso passar somente a palavra sem data, posso passar somente as datas, posso passar somente data inicial, posso passar a palavra com as datas.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer essa condição?

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statsCommand.SearchString))
    where = c => c.text.Contains(statsCommand.SearchString);

if (statsCommand.StartDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    where = c => c.date == statsCommand.StartDate;

if (statsCommand.StartDate != DateTime.MinValue && statsCommand.EndDate != DateTime.MinValue)
   where = c => c.date >= statsCommand.EndDate && c.date <= statsCommand.StartDate;
```

Depois faço a atribuição no result abaixo:

```
        result = await collection.AsQueryable()
            .GroupBy(c => c.details.text)
            .Select(d => new Details { text = d.First().details.text, date = d.First().details.date, Searchs = d.Count() })
            .Where(where)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.Searchs)
            .Skip((statsCommand.PageNumber - 1) * statsCommand.PageSize)
            .Take(statsCommand.PageSize)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Não estou sabendo fazer essas condições, sempre está vindo a ultima condição verdadeira e nao a junção delas todas.

Alguem poderia ajudar? Desde já agradeço

Comment: Você debugou o seu código e entende o que está fazendo?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo pq a pergunta? É claro que entendo O QUE PRECISO, eu nao sei como FAZER, por isso perguntei aqui....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você descreveu acima está resultando em um comportamento indesejado porque você sempre atribui algo novo à variável `where` (daqui pra frente vamos chamar essa variável de `filter` por se tratar do filtro para sua busca). Imagine que o campo `statsCommand.SearchString` não é nulo nem vazio, a variável `filter` receberá `c => c.text.Contains(statsCommand.SearchString)`, além disso o campo `statsCommand.StartDate` é diferente de `DateTime.MinValue`, então `filter` é sobrescrito para `c => c.date == statsCommand.StartDate` e essa variável pode ser sobrescrita mais uma vez caso a terceira condição que você colocou seja atendida. O que você precisa fazer para agregar todas essas expressões é usar o [linqkit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) que disponibiliza uma série de extensões ao `linq`, como por exemplo o operador `.And`. Primeiro importe o pacote [linqkit.core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LINQKit.Core/) para seu projeto e adicione-o na sua classe: `using LinqKit;`. Depois faça algo parecido com o que segue (como você não especificou sua collection na pergunta, imagine uma collection fictícia `IMongoCollection<Foo> collection`):

```
Expression<Func<IGrouping<Foo, Details>, bool>> filter;

if (statsCommand.EndDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    statsCommand.EndDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

filter = c => c.date >= statsCommand.StartDate && c.date <= statsCommand.EndDate;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statsCommand.SearchString))
    filter = filter.And(c => c.text.Contains(statsCommand.SearchString));

result = await collection.AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(c => c.details.text)
    .Select(d => new Details { text = d.First().details.text, date = d.First().details.date, Searchs = d.Count() })
    .Where(filter)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Searchs)
    .Skip((statsCommand.PageNumber - 1) * statsCommand.PageSize)
    .Take(statsCommand.PageSize)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Faça as adaptações necessárias, o exemplo acima foi apenas uma ilustração. O objetivo principal é você observar que caso `statsCommand.SearchString` não seja nulo nem vazio, uma nova expressão será agregada à `filter`.